# How do you patch objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, chalk

I have a module that patches [`chalk`](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) colors for my specific needs. Here's the code:

```
import { ChalkStyleElement, ChalkStyleMap, styles } from 'chalk';
import escape from './escape';

/**
 * Decorate ASCII-colors with shell-specific escapes
 */
let PatchedChalkStyleMap: ChalkStyleMap;

Object.keys(styles).forEach((style: string) => {
  PatchedChalkStyleMap[style] = {
    close: escape(styles[style].close),
    open: escape(styles[style].open),
    reset: escape(styles[style].reset),
  };
});
```

Above I just walk through all of `chalk` styles and patch them with my special `escape` function. However, this wouldn't compile. I get these errors:

```
src/colors.ts(10,3): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ChalkStyleMap' has no index signature.
src/colors.ts(11,16): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ChalkStyleMap' has no index signature.
src/colors.ts(12,15): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ChalkStyleMap' has no index signature.
src/colors.ts(13,16): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ChalkStyleMap' has no index signature
```

Also, I should say I have `"noImplicitAny"` options enabled in my `tsconfig.json`.

How can I describe types here correctly, without getting implicit `any`?

Answer (score 0):

**This method will patch the object**

```
// make sure your 'patchableObj' is not undefined otherwise error will occur.
PatchObject(patchableObj: Object, obj: Object) {
  try {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  
      if (value != null && value != undefined) {
        (patchableObj as any)[key] = value
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

What it is doing?
It is just avoiding the `null` or `undefined` values.

Answer (score -1):

You can augment the `ChalkStyleMap` interface to add the index signature:

```
declare module "chalk" {
    interface ChalkStyleMap {
        [key: string]: ChalkStyleElement
    }
}
```

If you don't want to modify the `ChalkStyleMap` interface, you can extend `ChalkStyleMap` into your custom interface, but you will have to use type assertion everywhere you use `styles` to ensure the compiler doesn't throw errors:

```
interface YourChalkStyleMap extends ChalkStyleMap {
  [key: string]: ChalkStyleElement
}

let PatchedChalkStyleMap: YourChalkStyleMap;
```

See [official documentation on merging interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)

Comment: Why? I'm already using chalk's typings and `ChalkStyleMap` is already declared [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chalk/index.d.ts#L93-L124)

Comment: @denysdovhan You are not re-declaring the `ChalkStyleMap` interface. You are simply augmenting it to add that indexer that you need..